# Is it possible to change the company identifier of an existing Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an existing Xcode project in which I've mistakenly set the **company identifier** as simply *companyName* rather than *com.companyName*. My bundle identifier renders as *companyName.productName* (which is as expected), but I'm hoping to be able to change this to the more correct *com.companyName.productName*.

I could simply change the bundle identifier in the plist, but is it possible to change the **company identifier** and have this change reflected in the bundle identifier and anywhere else it needs to show up? Or is changing the bundle identifier my best bet? And is there anything to look out for if I do? (The app has not yet been submitted, but I'm in the process of getting ready to do that.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it the bundle identifier ?

Comment: No, it's not the bundle identifier and yes it's possible. Just recently did that on a project, but I have to admit I forgot how - all I can say it's either in the settings or in the info.plist.  Just for the record: it does not necessarily influence your bundle identifier.